# Can you repeat a portion of a texture across a face?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm currently trying to texture a series of walls, all different lengths, but wish to use the same portion of a texture to cover them all.  I know that I can split up the walls into roughly equal panels, or spread out the wall UVs to various sizes until they repeat as necessary, but my goal is to keep the polycount low, as well as keep the texture usage to a minimum.  My goal is to dedicate a strip of my main texture (say 128x1024 of a 1024^2 texture) to a repeating wall panel, and then tile that across my walls using different materials.  Other portions of the texture will cover windows, floor tiles (which similarly need to repeat, though in two directions), posters, and fake room renders I'll be scribbling in myself.

tl;dr:

Is it possible to repeat just a portion of a texture map across a large face?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use some math nodes and keep simple proportions for you texture parts (for instance working with 1/2 or 1/4... easy to multiply or divide).

Here is an example :

[image]

Each face is assigned to a material composed of nodes like these ones (this material is for the red triangles) :

[image]

1. Amount of repeats
2. Shift U as the triangle starts at U = 0.5
3. Don't shift V as the triangle starts at V = 0
4. Modulos : here the texture is divided in 2 (so modulo = 1/2)
5. Shift back U to 0.5
6. Shift back V (but V starts at 0)

For the blue square, you may invert the roles for U and V.

For the green circle, just don't shift anything.

To reach the upper right quadrant, shift both U and V 0.5.

Comment: Great, this helps immensely.  It's going to take some twiddling with numbers to get things exactly like I need it on every wall, but I can already confirm it's tiling properly across two of them.

Comment: Just learning the node system at the moment.  Cycles too, apparently, since I couldn't find the nodes you were using right off.  I managed to group everything up so it makes more sense to me.  I also apparently fail at basic stackexchange inline image linking.

Comment: @Feynt, most of the nodes to do that are "math" nodes. It self is found in "converters".

Comment: Something I've noticed sadly is that when I repeat the texture I get odd lines to either side of my repeats.  I've done the math and my normal settings are exactly where the portion of the texture should begin and end, but even if I fudge it and go inside of those boundaries (so using a space narrower than the 1/2 I'm using now) I still get the seams.

[Nodes modification for grouping](http://i.imgur.com/XkSQJ3k.png)
[Seam issue](http://i.imgur.com/x7kJmkf.png)

Comment: @Feynt, can you upload the corresponding file (at least a mesh, the material and a texture) ?

Comment: I seem to be too late to add additional info each time.  [Link to .blend and .png texture](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8249157/Coffee%20Shop.zip).  I believe the materials will be in the file.  There might be a linking issue because I'm not including some furniture I added as links, but the room itself is what's important.  Wall Texture 1-4 make use of this repeating panel idea.  Wall Texture 5 and Floor are just using flat colours and so I stuffed their UVs into corners of the map with basic materials.  Better naming conventions forthcoming (I'm a programmer  >V  )

Comment: I think this is because the calculation assumes that UVs start at some point remove it / module / add this point position. But this point is at the beginning of the UV part. Here in your file, it can start in the middle. So that does not match.

Comment: What do you mean start at the middle?  It's ending at the middle for the repeating portions, so it should be like your circle example except it's 100% of the height of the texture instead of only 50% both ways.

Comment: are you talking about the bottom part (wood like) ?

Comment: Most of the walls make use of the entire span of the texture from top to bottom, using the wood slat portion as the bottom portion of the wall and the top portion as a generic wallpaper.  I'll be adding more texture to that eventually, but for now it's just flat colour.  The wooden slats are the important repeating segment.  Since that segment of the texture is 50% of the width and 100% of the height, it should be pretty straight forward calculating the nodes, but it's like the UVs are reaching beyond the texture boundaries, or it's blurring the edges and grabbing the other side.

Comment: @Feynt, I have tested with another texture and all is ok : the same texture as in my answer where I add a colored vertical line at 511 then another vertical line with another color at 512. No color overlaps. You can gain a little precision also using snap to pixels in the UV editor. I think you may tune your UVs using a grid on a texture to be sure all is ok